# If $q_i = q_j$ for all $i \neq j$ what's $\sum_{i=1}^n{\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}{q_i q_j}}$? (need confirmation)

Tags: summation

I need to evaluate the following sum and wanna recheck here that I'm not mistaken.
So can you please verify the corrctness or hint me to a mistake
\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^n{\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}{q_i q_j}}\\
= &q_1q_2 + \ldots + q_1 q_n + q_2q_3 + \ldots q_2q_n + \ldots + q_{n-1}q_n \\
\stackrel{q_i = q}{=} &\underbrace{q^2 + \ldots + q^2}_{(n-1)q^2} + \underbrace{q^2 + \ldots q^2}_{(n-2)q^2} + \ldots + \underbrace{q_{n-1}q_n}_{(n-(n-1))q^2} \\
=&q^2(n-1 + n-2 + \ldots + n - (n-1))\\
=&q^2((n-1)n - 1 - 2 - \ldots - (n-1))\\
=&q^2\left((n-1)n - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{i}\right)\\
=&q^2\left((n-1)n - \frac{(n-1)((n-1) + 1)}{2}\right)\\
=&q^2\left((n-1)n - \frac{(n-1)n}{2}\right)\\
=&q^2\frac{(n-1)n}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: this is all right

Comment: Appreciate it..

Comment: Ja, I was thinking about this. Is there some convention for those kind of sums? Here I basically presume $\sum_{i=1}^0{f(i)} = 0$. Maybe $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j>i}^n{q_i q_j}$ is more accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine, also with respect to the usage of an *[empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum)*
$\sum_{i=1}^{0}f(i)=0
$.

> Using the sigma notation and setting $q:=q_1$ we can write
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}q_iq_j&=\sum_{i=2}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}q_iq_j\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{i}q_{i+1}q_j\tag{2}\\
> &=q^2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{i}1\tag{3}\\
> &=q^2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i\tag{4}\\
> &=q^2\frac{(n-1)n}{2}\tag{5}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we start with index $i=2$, since the inner sum is empty when $i=1$.
- In (2) we shift the index $i$ to start from $i=1$.
- In (3) we factor out $q$ since $q=q_i=q_j$  for all $i\ne j$.
- In (4) we simplify the inner sum.
- In (5) we simplify the outer sum by applying the corresponding summation formula.